# Audio problems with Zencastr

Tags: zencastr

I tried [Zencastr](https://zencastr.com/) for recording audio in time of covid. I used Brave Browser, which I only use for one other application, and have 25 GB free on my device. I got this error:

> QuotaExceededError: You have run out of free disk space to save a local backup
> of this data. I recommend that you stop the recording and clear out some disk
> space to prevent possible data loss. Please see the system requirements for
> more information.

[image: Zencastr "Quota Exceeded Error"]

I continued the recording and it did not seem to be a problem, although I was only interested on the other side's recording and did not check mine.

More worrying is that the other side's recording seemed distorted on several occasions similar to a VOIP call with too little bandwidth. But Zencastr records locally and uploads at the end, so I don't understand the problem and want to make sure everything runs well before risking another recording on it.

Has anyone had this problem?

Comment: I just added [tag:zencastr]. Would you like to add propose a tag excerpt and wiki for it?

Comment: Yes, I have done so, thanks!